# http post request return 400

Tags: java, gitlab, apache-httpclient-4.x, postdata

I'm using HTTP post method to call Gitlab API which in return it gives me 400 response code.

I have tested the gitlab api with postman with providing propers headers and content body as JSON.
it worked fine and. ( I use gitlab create branch api )

I have debugged the application using eclipse and , there is some specific line which gave me `null`

I'm using apache http client 4.5.5 to handle http requests.

this is my first method to create a branch

```java
    public HttpResponse createBranch(String projectId, String branchName, String ref) {
        // url is ok, i debugged it
        String url = this.API_BASE_URL + projectId + "/repository/branches";
        //branchName = "uifix branch";
        //ref = "master";

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            obj.put("branch", branchName);
            obj.put("ref", ref);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Map<String, String> headerParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headerParams.put("Private-Token", PAT);
        headerParams.put("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
        headerParams.put("Accept", "application/json");

        return HttpUtility.httpPostForResourceCreation(url, headerParams, obj.toString());
    }
```

then will call the following method which is in httputlity class.

```java
    public static HttpResponse httpPostForResourceCreation(String url, Map<String, String> headerParam, String body) {
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

        StringEntity params = new StringEntity(body, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : headerParam.entrySet()) {
            request.setHeader(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

        request.setEntity(params); // I think problem is here. when I debugged it , it shows null.

        return execute(request);
    }
```

then will call the last method

```java
    private static HttpResponse execute(HttpRequestBase request) {
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpUtility.buildHttpClient();

        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(request);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 201) {
            System.out.println("resource successfully created: " + 201);
        } else {
            System.out.println("resource creation failed: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }

        return response;
    }
```

expected result should be "resource successfully created:  + 201"
instead of I'm getting "resource creation failed: 400"

here I attached my request object content
[image]

so, what I'm missing here ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: HTTP 400 means your request is incorrect, it should include in the response a description of what's wrong.

Comment: @ThisIsNoZaku I attached the request object content.

Comment: That doesn't say what the server thinks is wrong, that's in the response.